# Calculating Difference in Military time c++

Tags: c++

I've got the bulk of it down just confused on how to make the program spit out the correct answers when going from PM to AM. For example 2300 to 1000. Here is what I have so far:

```
void timeTraveled(int startTime, int endTime) {
    int min1 = (startTime / 100) * 60 + (startTime % 100);
    int min2 = (endTime / 100) * 60 + (endTime % 100);
    int ans1 = min2 - min1;
    if (ans1 > 0) {
        cout << "You have traveled " << ans1 << " minutes into the future!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        int ans2 = abs(ans1) + 24;
        cout << "You have traveled " << ans2 << " minutes into the future!" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you have travelled in the past if the start time was more than the end time

Comment: Here's something to think about. If end - start is negative, add 2400.

Comment: @everyone: I would assume it would be that time the next day.

Comment: What's a military time?

Comment: @Ron http://militarytimechart.com/

Comment: @Ron what most of the world uses instead of that crazy AM/PM nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of right answers to this one, its more just getting the math straight than anything to do with programming. Here is perhaps a more straightforward way to reason about it:

```
void timeTraveled(int startTime, int endTime) {
    if (endTime < startTime) { // Assume next day if endTime is before start time
        endTime += 2400;
    }

    int min1 = (startTime / 100) * 60 + (startTime % 100);
    int min2 = (endTime / 100) * 60 + (endTime % 100);
    int ans1 = min2 - min1;
    cout << "You have traveled " << ans1  << " minutes into the future!" << endl;
}
```

The way you had was close, it just had a couple simple errors in it:

```
void timeTraveled(int startTime, int endTime) {
    int min1 = (startTime / 100) * 60 + (startTime % 100);
    int min2 = (endTime / 100) * 60 + (endTime % 100);
    int ans1 = min2 - min1;
    if (ans1 > 0) {
        cout << "You have traveled " << ans1 << " minutes into the future!" << endl;
    }
    else { // Assume next day
        int ans2 = ans1 + (24 * 60); // Add 24 Hours worth of minutes
        cout << "You have traveled " << ans2 << " minutes into the future!" << endl;
    }
}
```